# Pronomen "es" oder "er"

Tags: gender, grammar-identification

About this sentence:

> Der Motor des Autos hat viel zu wenig Öl. Infolgedessen ist **er** kaputt gegangen.

Why it is *er* not *es*?

As I know *er* means *he* in English. So, *es* should be used as *it* in English.

Comment: I think this question should be closed due to not consulting a general reference. Any textbook will mention this within the first chapters. Mahmoud, FYI: German nouns have genders.

Comment: English and German are different languages, with different grammars.

Comment: I think answering my question, rather than closing it, would be more helpful. By the way, German, is not my mother tongue and that is why I asked this question. Thanks for c.p. for answering my question professionally...

Comment: Mahmoud: the suggestion to close was not intended as a personal slight. Much more advanced questions get closed around here, when the OP has not shown that he has not performed some prior research. Furthermore: i actually gave you an answer.

Comment: @Mahmoud While of course it would be helpful to you to answer the question, the site aims to be helpful to more expert users. Hence why we require questions — especially those that can be answered easily by a grammar book — to show prior research. Thus, closing is the correct choice here.

Comment: @Jan, it is new to me that this site is only for experts. If someone has never heard of grammatical gender before, how is he supposed to look it up?

Comment: @CarstenS I didn’t say *experts*, I said *more expert users*. And frankly, there is so much that people can’t look up if they haven’t heard it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst German and English grammars share many features, you face now something which is radically different: gender. *Motor*, in your example, is masculine. Therefore the pronoun should be also masculine, *er* (alternatively *der*). German does not quite obey English-pronoun rules regarding whether you treat an object or a person.

Comment: _es_ would be correct, too, if one wanted to refer to the car or the oil (_das Auto/Öl_).