# Use of ihn pronoun "ihn deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt."

Tags: pronoun, gender

I was reading the sentence

> Er hat den Film im Fernsehen verpasst und ihn deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt.

and it seemed relative easy to first translate and make sense:

*He missed the film on TV and he therefore later watched it on catch-up TV*

but I'm confused by ihn.

I would have thought that since "und" connects two main clauses, the second main clause would be

> Er deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt.

I know that ihn is the accusative of "er" but I can't see which verb requires "he" to be in the accusative, and also because "he" is the subject performing the action.

Why is "ihn" used over "er"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30666/1696), which got closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ihn* refers to the film, not to the person watching it: wen oder was hat er geguckt (sich angeschaut)? --> den Film.

Comment: Hi there, I'm just confused still. If Ihn [from (er)] is referring to the film, why not use "es" to get "and watched it later in the media library."?

Comment: because the film is masculine (_der_ Film) in German;

Comment: also: Er hat die Folge im Fernsehen verpasst und **sie** später in der Mediathek geguckt. Er hat das Lied im Radio gehört und **es** sich später auf CD gekauft.

Comment: so the reference to ihn is not to the subject (he), but a link to the gender of the item (der Film) which is masculine? hence I am referring to the film (gender-based pronoun usage)?

Comment: yes, exactly (see my answer above)

Comment: If we want to talk about _him_ we wouldn't repeat the pronoun: Er hat den Film im Fernsehen verpasst und deshalb später in der Mediathek nach ihm gesucht. (He missed the film on TV and therefore looked for it on catch-up TV later).

Comment: @Stef You could (or should) add your explanatory notes in the comments to your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your misconception comes from the English language, that only persons qualify for masculine or feminine pronouns. This is not the rule, but the exception as even a short look into German, French, Spanish dictionaries will reveal.

Here *Film* is masculine (dictionary entry therfore *Film, m., ...*) and *den* relates to film.

Answer (score 1):

The original sentence is a shortened version of the this sentence, which just is two full main clauses joined together with *und (and)* (I put square brackets around each main clause to make them better visible):

> [Er hat den Film im Fernsehen verpasst] und [***er hat den Film*** deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt].
>
> [He has missed the movie on TV] and [therefore ***he has*** watched ***the movie*** later in the media library].

<sup>*An even better translation would be:* "He missed the movie ..." *(without* "has"*) but I need the auxiliary verb* "has" *for didactical reasons.*</sup>

The subject *er (he)* and the auxiliary verb *hat (has)* can be omitted in the second part of the original sentence, just to make it shorter, giving:

> Er hat den Film im Fernsehen verpasst und ***den Film*** deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt.
>
> He has missed the movie on TV and therefore watched ***the movie*** later in the media library.

But to avoid repeated words, you can replace one of the appearances of the object with a personal pronoun. But since *»der Film«* is a masculine noun in German, while *»the movie«* is neuter in English, this pronoun has to be masculine in German (which gives one of: *er, seiner, ihm, ihn*) but neuter in English (which gives one of: *it, its*).

Now you only have to find the correct case, which is easy in English (it can't be genitive case, so the pronoun can't be *»its«* and so it has to be *»it«*). In German you must know which case the verb *»gucken«* (*to watch*) wants for its object. It wants its object in accusative case, so the pronoun has to stand in this case, and therefore it must be: *»ihn«*

So, this is the correct translation:

> Er hat den Film im Fernsehen verpasst und ***ihn*** deshalb später in der Mediathek geguckt.
>
> He has missed the movie on TV and therefore watched ***it*** later in the media library.